# how could I build python library from source code

Tags: python

I came across this issue that I don't have sudo access to install any software on redhat servers(python is installed). My python script depends a lot libraries. How could I use this libraries from the source code?

Comment: You don't need to recompile Python to use libraries.

Comment: Use pyenv, it's designed for using non-system pythons.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need root access to install libraries for Python.

Ideally you would use virtual environments, installing with `pip`, to isolate the different libraries needed by different applications. However, to achieve what you want the simplest solution is to create a directory in which you place the required libraries, then add that directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

When Python starts, it adds the directories from `$PYTHONPATH` to the `sys.path` list, so they are searched when the interpreter looks for libraries. See [this manual page](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for more details of how libraries are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If the python 3.3 or higher can use the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments), if not try to see if you have [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#usage)

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenv` has already been mentionned a few times and it's really the best way so far to manage per-project dependencies - but in your case it won't solve non-python system packages dependencies (GCC for non-pure python packages, and system libs and headers).